# Abbreviations list by using \DeclareAcronym : delete \ac{cip}

Tags: acronyms, thesis

I have one problem related to Abbreviation list:

First I define the abbreviations: such as

```
\DeclareAcronym{cip}{
short = CIP ,
long = Common Industry Protocol,
class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{gprs}{
short = GPRS ,
long = General Packet Radio Services,
class = abbrev
}
```

Then

```
\ac{cip} \ac{gprs}

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
```

The result is like this:

**Common Industry Protocol(CIP),General Packet Radio Services(GPRS)**

Then Abbreviation list..

My question is how can the system does not show the **Bold** part, only showing the abbreviation list. 
Because when I delete  `\ac{cip} \ac{gprs}` The list is empty, so nothing shows up...Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! May I guess: you're using the `acro` package?

Answer (score 2):

May I guess: you're using the `acro` package? Then you probably want `\acuse{cip,gprs}` or `\acuseall`. `\acuse` marks the acronyms listed in its argument as used without printing them. `\acuseall` marks *all* defined acronyms as used. Acronyms need to be marked as used in order to be listed in the list of acronyms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{cip}{
short = CIP ,
long = Common Industry Protocol,
class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{gprs}{
short = GPRS ,
long = General Packet Radio Services,
class = abbrev
}
\begin{document}
\acuseall
\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations]
\end{document}
```