# Abbreviation list

Tags: acronyms

I managed to add the abbreviation list by this way:

```
\DeclareAcronym{can}{
short = CAN ,
long = Control Area Network,
class = abbrev
}
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\ac{cip}
```

The result is like this:

```
 CAN Control Area Network 
Control Area Network(CAN)
```

What I want is only the first line with the abbreviation list, not the second line. Is there any way I can get rid of this? Because if I delete `\ac{cip}`, the whole list is empty...
Thanks a lot for help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: See [Abbreviations list by using \DeclareAcronym : delete \ac{cip}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253140)

Answer (score 0):

As posted in here [Abbreviations list by using \DeclareAcronym : delete \ac{cip}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253140/abbreviations-list-by-using-declareacronym-delete-accip)
  \begin{document}
    \acuseall
    \printacronyms[name=Abbreviations]
    \end{document}